# Storing and passing value between Controller and View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add an "Edit" button, when clicked it will show some values inside of a `from` allowing the user to change them and as well as adding two other buttons below "Confirm" and "Cancel".

What I'm having issues with is how to to pass the value if the "Edit" button has been clicked between the View and Controller, so that when it is clicked it will rerender so that the values appear in the form and the two buttons ("Confirm" and "Cancel") are shown.

From what I can tell you could store values in either `ViewBag`, `TempData` or have some value in the model which you can change. My understanding is that you cannot change `ViewBag` values from within the `View`, and therefore I would not be able to update the state of "Edit" button from pressing a button in the `View`. `TempData` does seem to possible to use to pass data from `Controller` to `View` and vice versa, but it's temporary and automatically removes it after retrieving a value so might therefore not be a suitable solution for storing values as well. Therefore, it only leaves the option of using a value in the model which is what I'm trying to do below, but I can't figure out how to make work.

Here is my View. `StudentGradeList.cshtml`

```
<table id="table">
     <tr>
         <td ><p>StudentName</p></td>
         <td><p>Grade</p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         @* If Edit is not pressed show StudentName and Grade*@
         <td><p>@ViewBag.StudentName</p></td>
         <td><p>@ViewBag.Grade</p></td>
         @* Else show StudentName and Grade inside text input allowing the user to edit the values. 
         Also add two buttons below ("Confirm" and "Cancel") where "Confirm" triggers database to update and cancel ignore changes
         *@
         </tr>

         <tr>
         @if (ViewBag.StudentName != null && ViewBag.Grade != null)
         {
         @* Call some function to trigger an update of the edit button value *@
         <td> <button value="Edit" type="button" onClick="ToggleEditButton()">Edit</button> </td>
         }

         else
         { 
         }
         </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my controller. `ViewController.cs`

```
 public class ViewController : Controller
{
    Models.EventModel myModel = new Models.EventModel();

    public ActionResult StudentGradeList(Models.EventModel myModel)
    {
        myModel.EditButtonValue = false;
        // ....
    }
```

And here is how I store the value in the model.

```
public class EventModel
{  
public bool EditButtonValue {get; set;}
}
```

Grateful for any input on how to change the code so that it is possible to store the `EditButtonValue`, get the value in `View` and changing it by pressing it.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from the controller to the view, you can use the `ViewBag` object. The `ViewBag` is a dynamic object that allows you to pass data from the controller to the view by setting its properties. You can then access the ViewBag properties in the view to retrieve the data.

In your code, you can set the `ViewBag.EditButtonValue` property in the controller, and then access it in the view to check if the edit button has been clicked.

Comment: I tried that previously, but the problem I had was that I coud not figure how to change the value of `ViewBag.EditButtonValue` when clicking the button in the `View`. Is the idea that you have some function for `onClick` which goes into the controller and there sets the value of  `ViewBag.EditButtonValue` to clicked?

Comment: To update the ViewBag.EditButtonValue property when the edit button is clicked, you can use JavaScript to call an action method in the controller that sets the value of the property.

Comment: I guess something like `$.ajax({ url: "@Url.Action("UpdateEditButtonStatus", "ViewController")"})`,   would be used for this? But it's not working.